# How to use passport-facebook with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, facebook, mongodb, passport.js

I'm having difficulty setting up passport-facebook with MySQL.

Everywhere I look I find mongodb, and using mongodb one can post the profile._json object into the database but with MySQL you can't.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID : "",
clientSecret : "",
callbackURL : ""
}), function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){

    db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE facebook_id = ?", [profile.id], function(err, user){
        if (err){
            return done(err);
        }
        else if (user.length == 0){


            var name = profile.displayName;
            var email = profile.emails[0].value;
            var username = profile.username;
            var provider = "facebook";
            var facebook = profile._json;

            db.query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, username, provider, token) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            [name, email, username, provider, /* profile._json?? */], function(err){

                })

        }
        else{
            return done(err, user);
        }

    });
});
```

What is the contents of profile._json that need to be saved and their types so that I can create fields in MySQL database?

Is there a possibility that maybe I should set up mongodb and save that info there and use MySQL databse for the rest? I am also using google authentication for my API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let user= {Facebook_ID: profile.id, First_Name: profile.displayName, FB_Private_Chat_ID: '000001100'};

  mysqlconnection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', user, (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Last insert ID:', profile.id);
  })
```